# creating private members on es6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm just wondering why everyone is saying to use WeakMap over Symbol for creating private members in a javascript class.

What's better about:

```
const NAME = new WeakMap();
class foo {
    constructor(name){
        NAME.set(this, name);
    }

    get name(){
        return NAME.get(this);
    }
}
```

versus:

```
const NAME = Symbol();
class foo {
    constructor(name){
        this[NAME] = name;
    }

    get name(){
        return this[NAME];
    }
}
```

is there a speed improvement or memory improvement with using WeakMap? The idea of having reflection available for use when using Symbol to me would be a win for using Symbol instead. So I guess my question is just why WeakMap over Symbol?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because symbols are not private. If you have a reference to an object, you can get its symbols:

```
var o = {};
(function trusted() {
  o[Symbol()] = "private data";
})();
o[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(o)[0]]; // "private data" - Oops!!
```

Instead, WeakMaps will be unreachable if you keep them confined in a trusted closure:

```
var o = {};
(function trusted() {
  var wm = new WeakMap();
  wm.set(o, "private data");
})();
// A reference to `o` is not enough to access "private data" :D
```

However, note they are not perfectly private neither:

```
var leaked;
(function attacker(_set_ = WeakMap.prototype.set) {
  WeakMap.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
    _set_.apply(this, arguments);
    leaked = value;
  };
})();
(function trusted() {
  var wm = new WeakMap();
  wm.set({}, "private data");
})();
leaked; // "private data" - Oops!!
```

Comment: Right, and I equate the Object.getOwnPropertySymbols to reflection and so IMO they are still private the same as C#/Java members can be marked private. Just like you can use reflection in C# or Java to set private members I do not see a problem that you can do the same in javascript.  Is this the main reasoning behind the aversion to using Symbol for private members?

Comment: @weagle08 I think this is the main reason. Well, in case of not owned objects, some people may think storing data in them is morally wrong.